# Klarna Checkout

Tags: checkout, customer, quote, guest-checkout, klarna

I am new to Magento and have built a Magento 2 multi-store site which uses the Klarna KCO (Checkout)

The checkout works fine except in the following usage:

- Add product to cart as guest
- Create new account (redirects to checkout)
- Checkout page loads
- As soon as the Klarna iFrame starts to load, the user is thrown out and sent back to login.

As the checkout loads the shipping in the summary states that there are 'no quotes available for this order'

Has anyone come across this issue? Running Magento 2.25 (cannot upgrade as the KCO does not have a M2.3 module yet) running latest KCO module.

I have tried everything I can think of, even stripping every theme and module off and leaving base luma theme with KCO and the same issue applies.

I believe it is an issue with the cart/quote, I am wondering if the cart/quote in the frontend cache is not updating in time for the user to hit the checkout so what is stored in the backend does not match or visa verse.

This issue doesn't happen if I disable the KCO module and use the standard Magento One Step Checkout.

The Klarna API is saying that the quote id does not match an order.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,